# Can 3 objects be collinear?

Tags: mass, velocity, geometry

Suppose there are 3 objects floating in some space, without anything else besides this 3 objects. 
Is there any way for them to end up collinear at any given moment (assuming they start at completely random positions, with completely random velocities)?
(The point to consider of each object is the center of mass)

**EDIT:** 
Many ask about the scenario and the physics to consider. The three objects are in an empty space, where there are only these 3 objects. And the physics act normally, as in any real space in our world.

I hope readers understand the point of my question. This trivially is very improbable, but the question is how improbable this is, and if there is a method to assure that this happens.

Comment: Yes but if they are moving randomly the probability is infinitely small. If you consider "almost" colineal to be good enough the probability goes up. Can you be more specific about the background of your question?

Comment: Are you considering gravity?

Comment: @floris that depends on the probabilities by which the 3-momemta are distributed.

Comment: What are the dynamics? How do they interact?

Comment: If the system is ergodic, it's a certainty that it'll happen

Comment: @innisfree in an ergodic system it will get arbitrarily close to being collinear, but the centre of mass being a point, the probability is still 0. Nevertheless I think this is indeed the correct context in which to formulate the question. Note that as soon as space is unbounded (as well as homogeneous), the system cannot be ergodic (as it will have unbounded measure). On a torus (i.e. with periodic boundaries) or with reflecting boundaries I guess it would be generically ergodic, so then indeed you would get arbitrarily close to collinear with probability 1.

Comment: Consider this problem in a 2 dimensional plane, as long as the velocity isn't parallel, they will indeed end up or have already been collinear.
On a torus they do seem to end up collinear but that is an analogy with the 2 dimensional problem (I think so). This is different.
In fact, the first case can be generalized and say that in an n dimensional space, any object of 2^(n-1)+1 objects will cross or will have crossed an n-1 dimensional cut given by the other 2^(n-1) objects.

Comment: -1. Not clear. (1) To what level of accuracy do you want the centres of mass to be co-linear? The more tolerant you are, the higher the probability. (2) Over what time frame are you considering? The longer the time frame, the greater the probability of it happening. (3) What forces act between the objects? Gravitational? Electrostatic? (4) What are the initial conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, though highly unlikely with random position and velocities.
The probability goes up with each of the following:

- They are in a closed space where they bounce off from the edge.
- Initial direction is towards the general direction of the other particles.
- If you consider any point on the object instead of only the center of mass.

You can calculate the probability of this happening using a monte carlo simulation with different parameters.

Comment: Probable but unlikely?!